# Haskell `kubernetes-client` docs browsing

Tags: haskell, hoogle

I am trying to use `kubernetes-client`, but the examples are quite minimal and I am having troubles doing anything. Is there a way to find "how to contruct type `X`" in hoogle? Or "what I can do with type `X`"? How do people deal with it?

One of many things I was trying to do is load a kubeconfig and check the context name. It *seems* like it should be possible, to get `Kubernetes.Client.KubeConfig` given `Kubernetes.Client.Config.KubeConfigSource`. That'd make a lot of sense, wouldn't it? And yet the search for `KubeConfigSource -> IO Config` gives me only useless generic results, like `throwIO :: Exception e => e -> IO a`. What can I do with `KubeConfigSource`? What are the ways to get `Kubernetes.Client.KubeConfig`?

Is it possible to find information like that by myself? How would I do that?